# MPMoviePlayer keeps playing after stream is done

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

We have an MPMoviePlayer which plays a stream. This works well, but we have 2 problems:

1. The player keeps playing after a movie is done, so the player closes and goes back to the app, but all of a sudden the we hear the audio of the movie again.
2. On the simulator, the movie plays fully, but on the device the screen freezes when the last segment is started. (the stream is a m3u8 stream file with fragments)

We have implemented the following method:

```
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification 
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];
    [player stop];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    self.view.hidden = YES;
    [player release];
}
```

What are we missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "pause" before "stop" like this :

```
[player pause];
[player stop];
```

Comment: We figured out that the m3u8 file had a bad bitrate, adjusted it and its running fine now. Just in case, I've added the pause.. Thanks mate!